# Issue with Running Rails Migration in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I created a migration in my development to change the column type from integer to date in my client table.

Migration:

```
class UpdateGradToDate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :clients, :grad_id, :date
  end
end
```

Which worked fine in development. However, once I push it to Heroku, I got the following error message.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "grad_id" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING grad_id::date".
: ALTER TABLE "clients" ALTER COLUMN "grad_id" TYPE date
```

I'm not sure how to correct this problem. I'm thinking perhaps using rails console and changing the column type there but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

I also tried creating a new migration using using this syntax as well

```
class ChangeDateFormatInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   change_column :clients, :grad_id, :integer
  end

  def down
   change_column :clients, :grad_id, :date
  end
end
```

I'm not really sure what to do at this point.

Comment: How could `grad_id` possibly be a date? Why not just add a new column that makes sense as a date?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is clearly explained by the PostgreSQL error:

> column "grad_id" cannot be cast automatically to type date

You are trying to convert a field that stores an integer, into a Date. The field could contain anything, including a value such as 10, 0 or -200. How those value could ever be converted into a Date?

What PostgreSQL is telling you is that you need to help him with the conversion.

Your best way is:

1. rename `grad_id` into `grad_id_legacy`
2. create a new `grad_id` Date field
3. run a script that reads each value from `grad_id_legacy` and stores the corresponding, converted Date value into `grad_id`

Comment: I would suggest reversing the order of your steps, i.e. create `grad_id_date` and then later rename it to `grad_id`, in order to minimize downtime. It's also possible to use a raw SQL ALTER TABLE statement with a USING clause to tell Postgres how to do the conversion, but it will lock the table for the duration of that process.